# Automatically prefill a webform from Client site

Tags: javascript, html, browser, firefox-addon, add-on

The Film-Production Software [Shotgun](https://www.shotgunsoftware.com/) offers a web interface.
To write notes, coordinator often have to fill in the same information into the forms, because there is no easy way to pre-fill the form automatically based on a project or page.

How can you prefill an autogenerated form, where you do not have access to the sourcecode of the website, which you would like to alter as a client automaticlly.

This is not trying to achieve, to alter the whole website on the web, rather just trying to alther the users html to improve the speed and remove redundant form entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to store this data in the cookies, although I do not know which implications this would have security wise. Ofcourse this would be much easier if there was a way to store this data server sided and collected from there.

Try creating a dictionary or JSON object based on the form, and store this data in the cookies. collect the data from the cookies if the user lands on the form again. The benefit from this is that you could implement this without ever actually handling the data, and being able to base it on a session so the cookies get cleared once a user drops the page.